# Preserving order of add operation encounter Concurrent list/queue insertion

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have multithreaded code where each thread needs to write to a shared list/queue. I want to ensure that multiple `add` operations can proceed concurrently and that the order in which each thread **encounters** the add operation is preserved. I do not want to synchronize the add operation if at all possible.

[image]

In the above image, green represents the thread that first encountered the add operation, blue represents the thread that encountered it second and red represents the thread that encountered it third. Even if red thread completed insertion before blue thread, I want the order to be effected as depicted.

I'm wondering if there are any existent suitable structures in the java concurrent package (LinkedBlockingQueue perhaps?) and if not, whether someone can offer any tips about what I would need to do in defining my own structure which could fulfill the requirements above.

My best guess at this point is to add a volatile `int` variable to the multithreaded code that increments immediately before the add operation, which is sent with the `Thread.currentThread.getId()` value, and can then be used after all write operations are completed, to sort the list/queue structure so that the elements are ordered according to the `int` variable's value at each element.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

It should be noted explicitly that insert operations need to take place in constant time.

Comment: A simple volatile isn't going to cut it, since you at least need atomic read-and-modify semantics.

Comment: maybe if I used an atomic integer?

Comment: You'll need that at least.  But whether the solution works as a whole is a different question, which I can't readily answer without seeing the code.  You may want to explore Java's priority blocking queue (I forget the class name) using the "arrival integer" as  priority.

Comment: Looking at `PriorityBlockingQueue` I don't think `add` operations could take place in constant time (I should have stated this is important to my code).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use ConcurrentHashMap and AtomicInteger as counter.

So every thread right before adding his ID to map calls the

```
 int id= AtomicInteger.getAndIncrement();
```

and the you put into ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> map

```
map.put(id, threadId);
```

then after the work is done you can sort entrySet by the key and you get the rigth order

alternatively you can use `ConcurrentSkipListMap` which will sort by the natural ordering of the keys, or by specified comparator.

But, i think that there is some part of the story that you still need to discover yourself, hard to say what it is now, just the picture you painted has some context and it seems like this context still hides something that you will discover. Just the problem you described comes from somwhere else, and it feel like the solution to it should be differnet than this kind of ordering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this and I don't think it works unfortunately. If I started a thread (th1) whose run method adds to a ConcurrentHashMap (map) then sleeps for 5 seconds and then after th1's run method added 1 second of sleep in the main thread, then created another thread (th2) whose run method does nothing but add to the map object, I would expect th1 to have been the first to add to the map, although with a little testing this doesn't seem to be the case. Any corrections to my approach, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedBlockingQueue` uses synchronization internally, in the form of `ReentrantLock` -- that's how it implements the 'blocking' part.

Something like this should work:

```
AtomicBoolean busy = new AtomicBoolean(false);

Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    while (!busy.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        // busy wait
    }
    try {
        list.add(Thread.currentThread().getId());
    } finally {
        busy.set(false);
    }
};
```

Here threads compete at the `busy` flag. One of them wins the right to add to the list, others busy-wait until the winning thread clears the flag.

The two calls to `AtomicBoolean` methods establish proper 'happens-before' relationship between `list.add()` calls done on different threads, so each thread should observe actual state of the list.

`LinkedList` can be used for unbounded queues. For bounded ones, maybe `ArrayList` with initial capacity set.

Comment: There is no need to immediately jump atomics. Keep in mind that this code, even if there is no lock, it is still blocking. If for whatever reason the thread that acquired the 'busy' lock is suspended, no other thread can make progress (so it has the blocking progress condition).

Comment: Apart from that, it can be very inefficient due to spinning.

Answer (score 0):

When calls are concurrent, by their nature, they are not ordered (that is what the word `concurrent` implies).

Ordering of requests based on the physical arrival time makes no sense; I do not know of any concurrency model that has such a requirement.

The simplest solution would be to use a synchronized wrapper around an AtomicList and add the threads to that list.

If you really want to go for a 'non blocking' data-structure, I would have a look at a concurrent ringbuffer like those from [JCTools](https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools/blob/master/jctools-core/src/main/java/org/jctools/queues/MpscArrayQueue.java). But before going for such a solution, I would first benchmark your code and figure out where your bottleneck is before just adding random complexity.